# How do I reference a port in the device tree?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, device-tree

**Edit:** this is a general question about referencing ports with phandles and the example I posted i.e. my particular case is not that relevant because meanwhile I have observed the same behaviour with other nodes.

I want to reference an existing port node from a device tree include (dtsi) and add an endpoint to it. That existing node is called mipi_in and is defined as a port inside another node (mipi_dsi):

```
mipi_dsi: mipi@ff960000 {
compatible = "rockchip,rk3399-mipi-dsi", "snps,dw-mipi-dsi";
reg = <0x0 0xff960000 0x0 0x8000>;
interrupts = <GIC_SPI 45 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH 0>;
clocks = <&cru SCLK_DPHY_PLL>, <&cru PCLK_MIPI_DSI0>,
   <&cru SCLK_DPHY_TX0_CFG>, <&cru PCLK_VIO_GRF>;
clock-names = "ref", "pclk", "phy_cfg", "grf";
power-domains = <&power RK3399_PD_VIO>;
resets = <&cru SRST_P_MIPI_DSI0>;
reset-names = "apb";
rockchip,grf = <&grf>;
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <0>;
status = "disabled";

ports {
  #address-cells = <1>;
  #size-cells = <0>;

  mipi_in: port@0 {
    reg = <0>;
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    ...
```

As I just need to add something to the port node, I referenced it in my device tree as follows:

```
&mipi_in {
  mipi_in_ep: endpoint {
    data-lanes = <1 2>;
    link-frequencies = /bits/ 64 <720000000>;
    remote-endpoint = <&device_ep>;
  };
};
```

But the compiler complains and points that the endpoint must be contained in a port node. But according to the mipi_in definition, it is already a port!
If I define a port node again, the compiler does not complain any more:

```
&mipi_in {
  port {
    mipi_in_ep: endpoint {
      data-lanes = <1 2>;
      link-frequencies = /bits/ 64 <720000000>;
      remote-endpoint = <&device_ep>;
    };
  };
};
```

But with that hack the hardware stops working properly, so I am wondering if a warning is just a bug in the compiler or if there is a cleaner way to reference the port.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Have you checked if there are other DT files in the kernel source that use this MIPI DSI (using compatible property)? Usually you can find such examples, and specially the DT binding for this controller in the kernel source Documentation can help you, and it often has some examples..

Comment: The examples just show how to use the node and not how to reference sub-nodes, which actually makes sense because otherwise all bindings with sub-nodes would have this repetitive information. In the end my issue might happen with any reference to any sub-node, it just happened with this one because it is the one I need. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable the device ... e.g. something like: `&mipi_dsi { status = "enabled"; }`

Comment: `&mipi_dsi {
        status = "okay";
};` does not help

Comment: Why did you use `"okay"` and not `"enabled"`?

Comment: because you must use `"ok"` or `"okay"` and not `"enabled"`. Please refer to the DT documentation.

Comment: You learn something new every day! You are correct - see [this](https://github.com/mykhani/device-tree-guide/blob/master/README.md#enablingdisabling-a-device) ... although why `okay` was chosen instead of `enabled` (the opposite of `disabled`) is a mystery (to me).

Answer (score 0):

Why the following is not working though dtc is not reporting any errors?

```
&mipi_in {
  port {
    mipi_in_ep: endpoint {
      data-lanes = <1 2>;
      link-frequencies = /bits/ 64 <720000000>;
      remote-endpoint = <&device_ep>;
    };
  };
};
```

The endpoint path is now something like

```
<>/mipi@ff960000/ports/port@0/port/endpoint
```

but if you refer the oirignal tree, it's

```
<>/mipi@ff960000/ports/port@0/endpoint
```

So, the driver must not be getting it correctly.

Not sure why the device tree compiler was reporting an error when you referred the port (most probably the dtc version doesn't support it), but you can try it like

```
&mipi_dsi {
    status = "okay";
    ports {
        mipi_in: port@0 {
            mipi_in_ep: endpoint {
                :
            };
        };
    };
};
```